# ASP.Net5 get current Ilogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, coreclr

I am using some Interfaces that happens to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`.

I want to know how to instantiate one Interface using the `Ilogger` noting that I only get `IloggerFactory` in

Here is what I have done but I don't know if this is right or not

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceCache, Cache>( Iapp => new Cache(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Debug")) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do:

```
#if DEBUG
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Debug"));
#else
    // here add logger for release or whatever other mode
#endif
```

The ILogger will be injected automatically in dependent services. So this should be enough:

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceCache, Cache>();
```

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IServiceCache, Cache>( app => new Cache(app.GetService<ILogger>().ToArray()[0] ); I assume this would be better instead of replicating the Logger